# Static website using S3 Route53 and CloudFront displaying outdated content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

After initially uploading the website, it was working perfectly. After some time, however, I uploaded a new `index.html` to my S3 bucket and saved the changes. After opening my website, it's still showing me the content of my old `index.html` page. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually CloudFront will pick up the new version (it caches files at many locations, which is the whole point of using it), but it can take a while for updated files to be distributed - usually longer than I like, so I either issue an AWS CLI command to create a CloudFront invalidation, or do it thru the console.

[Invalidating Files - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html)